how to run pySpark
I am new in Python and trying to run the code below in VS. But I am keep getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax. How to get around with this ?
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Dataframe').getOrCreate()
spark


Can you provide the full error traceback? It exists for a reason.

after reopening and rerunning the code what i am getting is;
ERROR: The process with PID 20712 (child process of PID 268) could not be terminated.
Reason: The operation attempted is not supported.
ERROR: The process with PID 268 (child process of PID 19804) could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
ERROR: The process with PID 19804 (child process of PID 10456) could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.

what is the syntax error traceback?
